# New Key Store: Key Store Path Problems

Tags: java, android, keystore, android-keystore

I am trying to create a new Key Store, in android studio, but when I click the three little dots (next to the Key Store Path text field) I can't click on a file to save the Key Store to it. I tried to type in the file, I wanted to save the Key Store to, but I get the following errors:

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The filename, directory
>   name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
>
> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Circle (Access is
>   denied)

All I want to do is run my app on a Real Device...why is this happening? How can I fix this problem??

Comment: All answers, questions, opinions, or hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (FINALLY) figured out the solution to my above problems!! So, the first thing you have to do is change your PC or Laptop account to Administrator. This will give you access to the previously Access Denied files. Then click the three dots....(as shown in the picture below)....

[image]

After that, click on the file you want to save the New KeyStore to. Now just copy the file's URL. Then just close that Choose KeyStore File window. Paste the File's URl into the KeyStore Path box. Finally, add your info, passwords, names, etc.

Your are now FINISHED! If all went well, then you should be able to click the OK button and be on your merry way! I hope this helps anyone who has had this problem!! If this answer has helped you, please UpVote either this Question or this Answer!